# Angular Validator function called multiple times

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am using Reactive form in project and I have this strange behaviour about form group validator.
I made a sample example to show you the problem

```
export class AppComponent {
  detailsForm: any;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.detailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required]
    }, { validator: [this.ValidForm] });
  }
  ValidForm = (formGroup: AbstractControl) => {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

<form [formGroup]="detailsForm" action="" id="maforme">
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
  <button type="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

The output is

```
hello app.component.ts:18
hello app.component.ts:18
hello app.component.ts:18
hello app.component.ts:18
```

My question why the validator was called 4 times in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validator is running every time the control in rendered on the UI and once when it is applied as a validator on the formGroup. You can verify this by removing the controls on UI.

Comment: is there anyway to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Thanks, if you find a solution, please feel free to leave a comment

Comment: I tried using the `{updateOn: 'submit' }` to the form controls, but even it didn't affect anything. Just out of curiosity, why would you need to prevent the validator from running multiple times ?

Comment: Hello; I was thinking to dispatch an action when the form is valid. But I don't want to be called multiple times. In fact, I resolve the problem with emit the new value of the form by adding a subject and for the subscribers I add debounce to ignore all redundant calls

Comment: @AdouaniRiadh Could you please share the snippet of code if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I used your example and found that when the application loads, the validator is called for:

- FormGroup in control
- FormGroup in html
- FormControl in html
- FormControl in html

You can reproduce this by commenting out the entire html with the form, and then returning it in parts and see the result in the process.

I think this is wrong behavior, but Angular works this way. I tested with version 7.1.0.

Answer (score -2):

I think , you need to replace AbstractControl with FormGroup in this line - ValidForm = (formGroup: AbstractControl).